# Grafana - Plugin

Tags: docker, plugins, grafana, zabbix

Good day!!
I have the following problem:
grafana:
│    image: grafana/grafana:latest
│    container_name: grafana
│    user: 'root'
│    environment:
│      - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app,raintank-worldping-app
│
│    volumes:
│      - grafana-config:/etc/grafana:rw
│      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana:rw
│      - grafana-home:/usr/share/grafana:rw
│    ports:
│      - '8020:3000'
│    depends_on:
│      - zabbix-server
│    networks:
│      - vpcstack

I'm not able to add the flowcharting plugin in version 0.9.0 in grafana, it says the plugin is unsigned.
I tried:
GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=agenty-flowcharting 0.9.0
GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=link to internet plugin - git
but it didn't work either.

Comment: It is really hard to understand what do you need (especially your formatting is a problem), but I guess this doc give you an answer https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#allow_loading_unsigned_plugins

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.